# Does material design form fields provide good UX?

Tags: forms, interaction-design, design, material-design

We recently changed our website design to use [Google's Material Design](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html). Quite a good number of long time clients had problems with the new forms layout.

Problems identified by us;

1. Presented with a blank form; "I had to figure out where to click first. I'm used to the old forms". Problem here is the missing box border.
2. The new forms seems to take more space than the flat design and the default ones.

For reference see:

[image]

Concern/question:

Will you recommend material design in an application where you need to present users with a lot of forms? Considering some forms are a bit complex.

Comment: Follow your users' feedback not Google's corporate style unless you're designing for Google's platform.

Comment: That's true @dnbrv but does it imply that this design concept works well only in some cases like mobile apps? I believe design principles should be around to help us keep things uniform and concise. Will this be a fail for Google's part? I guess I have a lot of questions to ask?

Comment: Hi Felix, not sure what kind of answer you're looking for. All we can say is "yes, I agree" or "no, I don't agree". You'd have to do your own tests to find out what is better for your users. As such, I've closed this. Please try to reword it if you meant something else.

Comment: We're facing the same issues as @felixcheruiyot. It's a shame this question has been closed - it would be really great to see how people with the same issue coped with it.